# Tidy approach to assess the agreement among dichotomised/binary parameters

Tags: r, dplyr, cross-correlation

We start with a dataframe of the following form:

```
my_df <- structure(
  list(
    a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
    b = c('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M1', 'M3'), 
    c = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
  ), 
  .Names = c("ID", "METHOD", "RESULT"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 8L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

In this simplified example, we have three methods (M1, M2, M3), three indivdiuals (1,2,3, and for 3, there are only results for M1 and M3 available), and two possible test results, 0 (negative) and 1 (positive). I would like to get an output that looks as follows:

|  | M1 positive | M1 negative | M2 positive | M2 negative | M3 positive | M3 negative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| if M1 positive | **100% (XX/XX)** | **0% (XX/XX)** | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) |
| if M1 negative | **0% (XX/XX)** | **100% (XX/XX**) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) |
| if M2 positive | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | **100% (XX/XX)** | **0% (XX/XX)** | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) |
| if M2 negative | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | **0% (XX/XX)** | **100% (XX/XX)** | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) |
| if M3 positive | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | **100% (XX/XX)** | **0% (XX/XX)** |
| if M3 negative | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | % (XX/XX) | **0% (XX/XX)** | **100% (XX/XX)** |

Or in words, I would like to know how much the result of a method, say M1 for example, coincides with the result of another method. As an output, I would love to get (1) the percentages (say, if M1 positive, then 22% of M3 is also positive) and (2) the absolute numbers (e.g., in 1000 that are positive for M1, 220 were positive for M3). Thus, the (XX/XX) stands for, e.g., number of positives for M1/number of positives for M3, in this particular example.

I have taken several approaches, trying to harness ifelse, if_else, and case_when but I am looking for a generic way, preferentially somewhere situated in the tidyverse, of doing it that will provide the array -- a cross-correlation matrix in a way -- I have in mind. Any help on how to aggregate the data would be appreciated.

Comment: In your test data, where is the link between tests?  For example, in row 1, we know that test `M1` produced a result of `0`.  But how do we know which of the results for `M2` and `M3` correspond to this `M1` result?

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected it now, I believe. In the heat of fire when trying to come up with a reproducible example, I forgot that the ID will be the link. Perhaps, an easier way of representing the data would have been in the wide format (one row, one ID, with columns representing results for different methods/tests) but I prefer the long format to make a solution generically applicable. Or so I hope. Thank you so much and please apologise my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, glue)

name_vals <- c("negative", "positive")

# join the data to itself, so every id, method, result row can see every other method and result with the same id
full_join(my_df, my_df, by = "ID", relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  count(METHOD.x, METHOD.y, RESULT.x, RESULT.y) |>

  # we need to complete the data, because the empty values in our final table have to be created using glue, using values_fiill doesn't work
  complete(METHOD.x, METHOD.y, RESULT.x, RESULT.y, fill = list(n = 0)) |>

  # create all the columns we will need for pivoting
  mutate(condition = glue("if {METHOD.x} is {name_vals[RESULT.x + 1]}"),
        name = glue("{METHOD.y} {name_vals[RESULT.y + 1]}"),
        value = glue("{round(n * 100 / max(sum(n), 1), 2)}% ({n}/{sum(n)})"), # max(sum(n), 1) because when a condition doesn't exist in our dataset, (for example, M3 positive in someone who also had M2), sum(n) == 0, dividing by zero gives us NaNs, which you probably don't want
        .by = c(METHOD.x, METHOD.y, RESULT.x))|>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = condition)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  condition         `M1 negative` `M1 positive` `M2 negative` `M2 positive` `M3 negative` `M3 positive`
  <glue>            <glue>        <glue>        <glue>        <glue>        <glue>        <glue>       
1 if M1 is negative 100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)     
2 if M1 is positive 0% (0/2)      100% (2/2)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    50% (1/2)     50% (1/2)    
3 if M2 is negative 100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)     
4 if M2 is positive 0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    100% (1/1)    0% (0/1)     
5 if M3 is negative 50% (1/2)     50% (1/2)     50% (1/2)     50% (1/2)     100% (2/2)    0% (0/2)     
6 if M3 is positive 0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)    0% (0/0)      0% (0/0)      0% (0/1)      100% (1/1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. What you have provided is (1) elegant, (2) amenable to be employed independent of how many methods there are, (3) and something I would not have been able to come up with, i.e., a learning experience for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have asked a slightly similar question elsewhere and unfortunately, so far nobody has been able to provide help, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036044/create-confusion-matrix-in-r-for-several-methods-and-several-references). I would be thankful for any suggestion.